# How to change computer name

Tags: windows-10, computer-name

I recently sent my computer for repair and when it came back, My computer name was replaced with the `Envy 15.HP` like shown in the image. How do i change this?

[image: Example of output]

Comment: `Envy 15.HP` isn't the computer name, it's the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is shown in your screenshot is not your computer name, it's your account's name.
Your Computer name is shown with command `hostname` - just type it into a cmd window and hit enter.

In folder `C:\Users\Envy 15.HP` are your documents, pictures, etc. stored by default.

You could create a new user account (please refer to [Microsoft's support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/5de907f1-f8ba-4fd9-a89d-efd23fee918c/)) and move your files from Envy 15.HP's folder to your newly created user directory.

Note that you have to log in with the new account and maybe delete the old Envy 15.HP account.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the name you're trying to change, you actually want to change the username. This should do the trick assuming that you have the necessary privileges:

```
wmic useraccount where name='Envy 15.HP' rename newnamehere
```

Otherwise, to change the physical computer name, here's what you need to do:

```
Start menu>type 'rename'>select 'Rename this computer'>click the 'Change' button
```

Then you should be able to figure it out from there. You will have to reboot your system for the changes to take effect. Hope this helps!

Comment: question. Where do i enter this command

Comment: The command prompt. Make sure you're running it as an admin (right click>run as administrator)

Comment: It says no Instance available

Comment: and the rename, i couldn't find it

Comment: Are you on Windows 7 or 10?

Comment: As said in the tag and the version in the CMD, Windows 10

Comment: Oh! My mistake, I'm new to stack so I'm still used to the site. You can probably do it this way then: control panal>user accounts and family safety >user accounts>change account name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44535/discussion-between-aud-io-and-luciferangel).